# Help needed in evaluating disk condition

Tags: server, disk, smart

I have a disk on and ubuntu server that I am not sure if it is failing or not. 
I installed smartctl via the command line, and piped the output to a file. the computer it is in, is a server in a remote sensor network, I really need to know if the disk is having problems or not, while I am in the area and able to repair it. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to interpret the output of smartctl. 
http://pastebin.com/XiGPdYb4

Any insight as to the condition of this disk, and the output of smartctl would be appreciated. Alternatively if there was a simpler tool to use to check the disk integrity on a server, I would also like to know what that is.

Comment: Yeah everything looks good, is this disc part of a RAID array? What caused you to run this test? What are your concerns?

Comment: No its not a member of a RAID. I run the test because I was currious, then i saw the "error 106" and such, and got concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every part of that report looks good and healthy.  It even has less than a year's worth of power-on hours on it.  It also happens to be my favorite brand.  Do you have any particular reason for being suspicious of it?